# how to connect to wireless connection

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i cannot connect to the ubuntu 12.04 wireless connection

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141521/how-to-connect-to-wireless-connection/) by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-18**:
I think with such kind of questions your wrong at ROS answers. Try http://askubuntu.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try buying a wireless cable on ebay to connect your VM to your host system.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2